# SelectedItem in gridview combo box

Tags: winforms, telerik-grid, radgridview, radcombobox

I have populated combobox from database in my `RadGridView` and I want that when it is in add mode my combobox shows its first item as default value. I used following code but I have Error in debuging on commented line in code

```
      private void radGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

                    if (e.Column.Name == "Productcolumn")
                {
//ERROR on debuging following line
                    RadDropDownListEditor ed = this.radGridView.Columns["UnitPrice"] as RadDropDownListEditor;
                    if (ed != null)
                    {
                        // the default selected Price that will be shown will be the first price, if no price is selected for the current cell
                        RadDropDownListEditorElement editorElement = (RadDropDownListEditorElement)ed.EditorElement;
                        editorElement.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What error your getting?

Comment: andy when I press F5 to run it gives error on commented line

Comment: @andy please help me on this